# Get more than 7 dimensions in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am fetching my data from **google analytics core api**. I came to know that we can **fetch only 7 dimensions** using api, But here I need to fetch more than 7 dimensions with correct metrics. Is there anyway (other than using paid google analytics) to fetch more than 7 dmensions with correct metrics from google analytics.

If not, then is there any mathematical formula through which we can find intersection of dimensions fetched using 2 different dimensions having one dimension in common.

Thanks

Comment: For anyone facing the same challenges. I can suggest the app from https://www.scitylana.com which can extract and give you access to way more that 7 dimensions in a unsampled, hit-level dataset (future, not historic data). It's also possible to do this yourself. GA specialist Simo Ahava has an article about this subject. https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/improve-data-collection-with-four-custom-dimensions/ We just took it a bit further. (scitylana is my company)

Answer (score 2):

The only way I have found around the 7 dimension limit is to be creative with filters.  It will mean that you are sending more queries to the server, but if you aren't worried about your quota limit then its doable.

Example: ga:visitorType  only has two values.   New Visitor, Returning Visitor

So you could run a query with your 7 dimensions. Then add A filter   ga:visitorType=New Visitor  then run the same 7 dimensions with a filter added of ga:visitorType=Returning Visitor
Bingo you just got an 8th dimension.

Again you need to be a little careful because you are going to increase the number of queries you run by each value of dimension you are doing creative filtering on. I wouldn't recommend doing it with say ga:landingPagePath because the number of landing pages you have is to big. You will end up running too many queries. But there are a few you can do this with. ga:isMobile, ga:deviceCategory,  ga:date. Just remember the more creative filters you add the more queries you end up running. I had one where I ended up expanding it to 80 requests just to get the data back I needed. Scary but it worked.

Comment: I think in filters you can give only fields which are part of  your dimensions.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh You can filter for a dimension or metric that is not part of your query, provided all dimensions/metrics in the request and the filter are valid combinations. Comes directly from https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters  That and i have used this method so i know it works

Comment: Another "creative" solution (that would only work for future data) might be to set up view filters that copy all the relevant dimensions to one custom dimension. Then you would query that and split the query results along a delimiting character back into separate dimensions. Not elegant, but might save many API calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you have specific dimensions that can be used to identify a session at a specific time (e.g. a session ID and browser timestamp), you can execute multiple queries then patch them together.

I built a python program that will do exactly this: https://github.com/aiqui/ga-download

This program can bring together multiple groups of dimensions, so that any number of dimensions can be downloaded and combined into a single CSV file.