# More than 7 Dimensions In pentaho Google analytics transformation

Tags: google-analytics

How can we pass more than 7 dimensions in pentaho google analytics.I am new to pentaho.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: to be more specific..

Answer (score 1):

The Google analytics API limits you to a maximum of 7 dimensions and 10 metrics.  [Pentaho](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Google+Analytics) uses  Google Analytics 2.4 API so you can't request anymore.

The only way that I know of to extract more information is to use [BigQuery](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com) with a premium GA account.

Not exactly the same question but: [Get more than 7 dimensions in Google Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720486/get-more-than-7-dimensions-in-google-analytics)